# Encoding a string as an integer .NET

Tags: string, encoding

I have a string that I would like represented uniquely as an integer.

For example: A3FJEI = 34950140

How would I go about writing a EncodeAsInteger(string) method. I understand that the amount of characters in the string will make the integer increase greatly, forcing the value to become a long, not an int.

Since I need the value to be an integer, I don't need the numerical representation to be entirely unique to the string.

Maybe I can foreach through all the characters of the string and sum the numerical keycode of the character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If these are your requirements:

1. Some sort of string → integer mapping.
2. Integers don't have to be unique.

Then you're in luck, because this is exactly what the [`GetHashCode()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.gethashcode(v=VS.100).aspx) method does! The MSDN page gives some sample hash codes. Note that these are completely arbitrary and can change in future versions of the CLR.

> The hash code for "" is: 0x00001505, 5381
>   The hash code for "a" is: 0x0002B5C4, 177604
>   The hash code for "ab" is: 0x00596E26, 5860902
>   The hash code for "abc" is: 0x0B873285, 193409669
>   The hash code for "abd" is: 0x0B873282, 193409666
>   The hash code for "abe" is: 0x0B873283, 193409667
>   The hash code for "abcdef" is: 0x4DDB4BE2, 1306217442
>   The hash code for "abcdeg" is: 0x4DDB4BE3, 1306217443
>   The hash code for "abcdeh" is: 0x4DDB4BEC, 1306217452
>   The hash code for "abcdei" is: 0x4DDB4BED, 1306217453
>   The hash code for "Abcdeg" is: 0x941C4FC3, -1810083901
>   The hash code for "Abcdeh" is: 0x941C4FCC, -1810083892
>   The hash code for "Abcdei" is: 0x941C4FCD, -1810083891

Comment: thanks for the great info! my requirements made me go with a solution that would have the same result in all versions of .net

Comment: Then use the Cryptography namespace to get a hash that won't change: http://asp.dotnetheaven.com/howto/doc/hash.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
    protected int EncodeStringAsInt(string value)
    {
        return value.ToCharArray().Sum(c => Convert.ToInt32(c));
    }
```

Comment: This will give a LOT of duplicate mappings compared to a real hash algorithm, e.g. BAT and TAB have the same value.

Comment: @Eric J - you can exclusive or (^ operator) each subsequent character than sum to avoid simple bat/tab issues, but yes, a cryptographic hash would be better.

Comment: @Joel: I used XOR back in the day too :-)  As you say, it's better but not as good as cryptographic hash that you get from .Net.  How would you express that in Linq though?

Comment: @Eric - with the .Aggregate() extension method.